# How to intercept when a JDBC connection is being taken out and returned to the JDBC connection pool?

Tags: hikaricp, micronaut, micronaut-data

I'm trying to figure out how to intercept the actions of a JDBC connection being taken out from the JDBC connection pool, and just before it's being returned.

Comment: What connection pool are you using and what runtime environment (servlet container or netty)?

Comment: Hikari for pool and netty for runtime.

Comment: I do not know the answer but https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/141 looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: Hm. Well, this is a greenfield project and very early in its development, so we are not married to a particular connection pool implementation. Is there an option that would make this easier?